# How to import com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector

Tags: java, android, gps

I am working with a map application in android. To use some gesture methodes i need to import the following,

```
import com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector;
```

But this shows an error like "the type com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector is not visible". What is the problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are importing the wrong class, you should import android.view.GestureDetector;

Comment: i think the GestureDetector can only deal with a normal View, not a Mapview. I got double tap events in a normal view but same code is not working with a mapview. Thats why i am trying this onGestureDetector interface.

Comment: So maybe you should extend the mapview class to make your own and then use the GestureDetector I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

like you wrote "the type com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector is not visible" means that the class is not defined in public scope, so it's an internal one and is not intended to be used by "us"